# iOS: Use en.lproj resources even user current language is non English

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

My apps provide both Japan and English localization stuffs.

However, some users prefer to use en.lproj resources of my app, even their current iPhone is using Japan as default language, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, not by default. You could roll your own localization stuff, but that would probably be a nightmare.

#### Old answer:

Have the resources copied directly into the `Resources` folder instead of being in `en.lproj` (i.e., don't localize them).

Comment: No, I mean user have the option to change the language, so they can either change to English or Japanese, without changing the iPhone's setting.